# How to connect android mobile application with MS SQL server 2014

Tags: android, sql-server, database, connectivity

I'm making an application for my project in which the backend database has to be on MS SQL sever 2014 and i'm making android application as front end. I really don't know any specific way to do this connectivity, i have searched alot and got to know about JDBC but i don't know how to get along with.

Your answers will be really appreciated.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiCm6jUQKCA quick google search.

Comment: Thanks, but i have seen this and it's on Ittia Db and we i have to work with database on ms sql server.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a webservice for this. If you'll just deploy your app locally then run your webservice locally. Use the Android AsyncTask class to connect to your database by making a post or get request via webservice. Your webservice then will be responsible for all the database query.

So the data diagram would be something like this.

Android App <----> WebService <----> Database

After the WebService gets the necessary data from the database then it could now send those data back to the android application who made the request. You can choose different ways for making a webservice like by using ASP.NET, PHP, or JAVA.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You should use WebService handle this. You can very easy use [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) (PHP micro framework ) To cope with all sorts of different language and context.